# Display changes between two directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Okay this is about my fifth thread on the topic because I'm balls-out lost in every aspect of this horrendous assignment. I've used other solutions that worked perfectly but cannot be employed such as using the `awk` command, `sed`, and `comm`. Instead, gotta do this the hard way.

I am so lost, at this point I'm not even doing it to hand it in because it's a zero since it's past the due date, I've been tearing my hair out for the past 18 hours trying to get this done just for the sake of getting it done. Much appreciated if you can save me from putting a bullet into my head.

**Point of the assignment:** You are to write a Bash shell script which will help compare the contents of two directories. Write a utility that satisfies the following requirements:

1. Your script will compare filenames
   in two directories, and list
   information about filenames that are
   in one directory but not the other.
   The information listed will be a
   long listing of each file, similar
   to the "ls -l" command. The
   directory names must be specified,
   including any required absolute or
   relative paths.
2. Your script will work for all kinds
   of files, including directories that
   are contained in the specified
   directories. The script will print
   an appropriate error message if the
   number of arguments passed to it is
   something other than 2, or if the
   directory names specified are not
   names of valid existing directories.
   If an error message is issued, then
   the script should end with an exit
   status of 1 (one). Otherwise, it
   should end with an exit status of 0
   (zero).

**Specifications:**

1. Files in the directory that this
   script is supposed to work on don't
   have execute permissions, only read
   which if I'm not mistaken can only
   display file names, so we can't see
   file contents. I tried, I get
   permission denied.
2. All information regarding this
   assignment can be found here:
   https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~lczegel/BTO120/assign1/assign1.html

**What I have done:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d $1 ]
   then
      echo $1 is not a valid existing directory >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ ! -d $2 ]
      then
      echo $2 is not a valid existing directory >&2
         exit 1
   elif [ $# = 0 ]
      then
         echo Usage: compdir dir-name1 dir-name2 >&2
         exit 1
   elif [ $# = 1 ]
      then
         echo Usage: compdir dir-name1 dir-name2 >&2
         exit 1
   elif [ $# = 2 ]
      then

         ls -a $1 > temp1
         ls -a $2 > temp2

         cat temp1 |
         while read input
         do
            grep -Fvf temp1 temp2 > temp1_diff
         done

         cat ~temp2 |
         while read input
         do
            grep -Fvf temp2 temp1 > temp2_diff
         done

         #Files that are in $1 but not in $2
         cat temp1_diff |
         while read input
         do
            Files that are in $1 but not in $2
            cd $2
            ls -la `cat ../temp1_diff`
         done

         cd ..
         echo -e

         #Files that are in $2 but not in $1
         cat temp2_diff |
         while read input
         do
            Files that are in $2 but not in $1
            cd $1
            ls -la `cat ../temp2_diff`
         done

   elif [ $# = 3 ]
      then
         echo Usage: compdir dir-name1 dir-name2 >&2
         exit 1
   else
         echo Usage: compdir dir-name1 dir-name2 >&2
         exit 1
fi
```

**The problems I am encountering:**

1. It will not write any files that
   have any characters like dots or
   spaces or anything in them to
   temp1_diff and temp2_diff.
2. I cannot get the echo to echo once
   even if it's before or in the loop.
3. I get constant errors that it cannot
   navigate to $1 or $2 etc.

Comment: You only need execute permission on files to run the programs that they contain; you only need read permission on the files to see the contents.  (If it is a script, you need both read and execute permission; if it is an executable, you do not need read permission on the file to execute it.)  With directories, read permission allows you to list the directory contents; search (execute) permission allows you to read the files in the directory - subject to file permissions too, of course - and to make the directory your current directory if you so choose.  [...to be continued...]

Comment: [...continuing...] Again, you can have execute permission without read permission on a directory; if you know the name of the file, and have permission to access the file, you are allowed to do so, but you can't list the contents of the directory to find out what is in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time, there was a program called `dircmp` that did quite a lot of what is requested - the main difference being that it did not do `ls -l` format listings for files found in but not the other directory.  That will require some hacking.  Some time ago it became clear that `dircmp` was going the way of dinosaurs, but there's enough of the palæontologist in to create a version that works for me.  It will likely give you some issues if you have to deal with filenames containing blanks, tabs or newlines, but otherwise is likely to usable.

Here is the not complete answer to your assignment, but at least a workable start point.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#       @(#)$Id: dircmp.sh,v 1.6 2003/03/12 08:29:13 jleffler Exp jleffler $
#
#       Simulation of the much-loved dircmp(1) script, with extensions.

arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)

error(){
        echo "$arg0: $*" 1>&2
        exit 1
}

dflag=0 # Files that are different
mflag=0 # Files that are missing in one or the other
sflag=0 # Files that are the same in both (or directories, or otherwise special)
while getopts dms flag
do
        case "$flag" in
        (d) dflag=1;;
        (m) mflag=1;;
        (s) sflag=1;;
        (*) echo "Usage: $arg0 [-dms] dir1 dir2" 1>&2; exit 1;;
        esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)

# If user set no flags, set them all (traditional behaviour of dircmp).
if [ $sflag = 0 ] && [ $dflag = 0 ] && [ $mflag = 0 ]
then dflag=1; mflag=1; sflag=1
fi

if [ $# != 2 ]
then echo "Usage: $arg0 [-dms] dir1 dir2" 1>&2; exit 1 
elif [ ! -d "$1" ]
then error "$1 is not a directory"
elif [ ! -d "$2" ]
then error "$2 is not a directory"
fi

tmp="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/dc.$$"
trap "rm -f \"$tmp\".?; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

(cd "$1" 1>&2 && find . -print | sort) > "$tmp".1
(cd "$2" 1>&2 && find . -print | sort) > "$tmp".2

{
if [ $mflag = 1 ]
then
        comm -23 "$tmp".1 "$tmp".2 > "$tmp".3
        comm -13 "$tmp".1 "$tmp".2 > "$tmp".4 
        if [ -s "$tmp".3 ] || [ -s "$tmp".4 ]
        then
                long=$(awk '{if(length($0) > len) { len = length($0); }}
                                END { print 2 * len + 6; }' "$tmp".3 "$tmp".4)
                echo "Files in $1 only and in $2 only"
                echo
                pr -w$long -l1 -t -m "$tmp".3 "$tmp".4
                echo
        fi
        rm -f "$tmp".3 "$tmp".4
fi

if [ $sflag = 1 ] || [ $dflag = 1 ]
then
        comm -12 "$tmp".1 "$tmp".2 > "$tmp".5
        if [ -s "$tmp".5 ]
        then
                case $sflag$dflag in
                (11) echo "Comparison of files in $1 and $2";;
                (01) echo "Files which differ in $1 and $2";;
                (10) echo "Files which are the same in $1 and $2";;
                esac
                echo
                cat "$tmp".5 |
                while read file
                do
                        if [ -f "$1/$file" ] && [ -f "$2/$file" ]
                        then
                                if cmp -s "$1/$file" "$2/$file"
                                then [ $sflag = 1 ] && echo "same                $file"
                                else [ $dflag = 1 ] && echo "different           $file"
                                fi
                        elif [ $sflag = 0 ]
                        then continue
                        elif [ -d "$1/$file" ] && [ -d "$2/$file" ]
                        then echo "directory           $file"
                        elif [ -b "$1/$file" ] && [ -b "$2/$file" ]
                        then echo "block special       $file"
                        elif [ -c "$1/$file" ] && [ -c "$2/$file" ]
                        then echo "character special   $file"
                        elif [ -p "$1/$file" ] && [ -p "$2/$file" ]
                        then echo "named pipe          $file"
                        else echo "***dubious***       $file"
                        fi
                done 
                echo
        fi
fi
} |
uniq

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
```

Comment: That's far far more complicated than what we touched upon in this course. Also I mentioned comm can't be used.

Comment: @soju: OK, that's the problem with exercises; they impose artificial limitations on a solution that are irrelevant in the real world.  In the real world, you use the best tool for the job, subject to appropriate constraints.   So, you'll have to work a bit harder, but `comm` is not a dreadfully hard program to simulate.  It is basically read a line from each file, and decide whether the two lines are the same.  If yes, read a new line from each file; if not, output the line that sorts earlier, and read the next line from that file.

Answer (score 2):

How about approaching it this way:

```
for f in `ls -a $1`
do
    if [ -r $1/$f ] && [ ! -x $1/$f ] && [ ! -r $2/$f ]
        then 
            echo "$f Not in other dir"
```

Now you know that the file is in your first dir, but not the second.

**Edit:** changed to check if file in first dir is readable + not executable per specs in question - that will tell you if it's not in the other dir with read permissions

Comment: I upchecked this, but I'll also suggest `ls -A` each directory to separate temp files, then filter through the `comm` command.  I'd do comm at least twice (for different filenames and for similar filenames) rather than try to parse the output in one go.  Then do `ls -l` for each file as necessary.

Comment: I'll grant you that your approach would work, but why go to all that trouble? Plus you don't have the permissions (though his question is a bit unclear on that part). You might be correct on the `-A` but the requirement said it had to work with directories so that's also a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can list the whole tree by using find. If you want the tree "based" in the same place, do `find $the_dir -printf '%P\n' > somewhere`. (otherwise find will prepend `$the_dir` to every line, making comparisons harder)
2. Instead of checking every single line separately, keep in mind that if you have a file with both directory contents listed, you can just take unique lines from it. Use `uniq -u` for it. (requirement doesn't say you have to tell where the file is / isn't)
3. Don't check the argument count many times, it's either == 2, or it should go into the `else` clause.

Also, the comment about file permissions is wrong - if it has +r, you can read it. If the file has +x, you can execute it. Whether you see the file depends only on the containing directory's permissions.